# Can't push to an array in the global scope using a push command wrapped inside jQuery's "on click" event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Pretty much what the title says.

In the console the array with the pushed value only exists for the blink of an eye and can't be recalled. The number is irrelevant, just trying to push to the array for now.

```
var storage = []

$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    storage.push(5000000)
})

//  Does this...
//  console.log(storage) => [] 

//  But I want this...
//  console.log(storage) => [5000000]
```

Comment: Where is your console log being called? No reason `push()` won't work as shown. Provide [mcve] or we can't reproduce based on what is shown

Comment: where did you place `console.log(storage)`? when is that executed

Comment: is your submit definitely receiving the click event? (use console log inside there). Also, are you checking the value of storage after you click? Or just after you add the on click handler?

Comment: Submit buttons submit.... It refreshes the page, array will be reset...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible that you are using a click event but not preventing the default behaviour which is to go to that page (if its a link) or submit a form (if its a submit input type).

Your code looks right but maybe try adding the event parameter and call its preventDefault() method:

```
var storage = []

$('#submit').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    storage.push(5000000);
});
```

This will add the number to storage and it will not carry out the click action which will refresh the page or go to another location. This way you can keep adding things to storage.

Then do a console.log after a few clicks in the debugger.

If you want to retain the data in storage but allow new page loads then you will need to look into html5 storage capabilities or even using cookies to store the data. HTML5 storage would be easiest. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( storageAvailable('localStorage') ) {

        $('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
            // e.preventDefault();

            var storage = localStorage.getItem('storage');
            console.log(storage);

            if( storage === null ) {
                storage = [];
            } else {
                storage = JSON.parse(storage); // retrieve json data as an array not as the json string value we set it as later
            }

            storage.push(500000);

            localStorage.setItem('storage', JSON.stringify(storage)); // store array as a string value as local storage only deals with strings

        });

    }
})

// taken from MDN site
function storageAvailable(type) {
    try {
        var storage = window[type],
            x = '__storage_test__';
        storage.setItem(x, x);
        storage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can get a console log by retrieving the data like so: `console.log(localStorage.getItem('storage'));`

Comment: Ummm what about the form submit?

Comment: If the element selected is the submit button then this will still prevent the form from submitting. I tested this on jQuery 1.12.4. Not sure if this is valid on all versions of jQuery though.

Comment: Right... and that's the point...now OP's form isn't going to submit and there is no mention of how they need to handle that. There simply isn't enough detail given in question to provide a proper answer

Comment: I see. Yeah, I have no clue what the OP wants lol. Wasn't sure if it was a submit form or just a submit value button for the purpose of client side use only. I am editing my answer as we speak for an alternative solution though.

Comment: More appropriate thing to do is vote to close since question has no long term value for anyone as it stands now

Comment: Hey JoeMoe1984, thanks that totally works. My code example was a little out of context, I'm just trying to push an object with user generated input (name, phone, email) into an array of users.

I'd upvote you but I'm a total newb. Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeFleming So did my example solve your problem? Because if it did then you can check it as the correct answer. No need to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It works!

https://jsfiddle.net/buk2ment/1/

```
var storage = []

$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    storage.push(5000000);
});

$('#submit1').on('click', function(){
    console.log(storage);
});
```

If you're putting output in console just after click event that will fail, as you're feeding values into array after click only.

After single click on `submit` button whereever you access storage array you will have the values inside an array until the page is refreshed.

Check above example to get the clear picture.